# Don't see "Dimensions" in Transform (N) pannel - checked

Tags: interface, dimensions

I'm newbee here and already have some troubles with "Dimensions" panel - the thing is that I haven't it by some reason. What I did wrong? [image]

Answer (score -1):

Aaah, it's not look like a solution, but when I deleted the default cube and created new one, dimensions panel appeared

Comment: You had a lamp object selected, lights have no dimensions